Create Eslint plugin as part of library?
I don't want to publish an eslint plugin as an own npm artifact to share it with other projects.
Instead I already have a npm package published which other projects use.
So is it possible I put the Eslint plugin there, and the other projects can extend it ? Instead of having 2 npm artifacts published and having to maintain , I still have only the original one.
Thanks for your help!

Yes, this is possible. ESLint's new "flat" config (https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files) allows importing plugins as plain old JavaScript. See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/plugins.
For example, if your plugin is located in ./packages/eslint-plugin-example, your config might look something like:
// eslint.config.js
import example from "./path/to/eslint-plugin-example";

export default [
    {
        plugins: {
            example
        },
        rules: {
            "example/rule1": "warn"
        }
    }
];

If you're using using workspaces such as through npm (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces) or another package manager, that import path might just be "eslint-plugin-example" instead. It depends on how you've structured your repository.
